# jquery draggable over function

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

i just want the OVER function block gets called after 4-5 seconds
 **wen i hold the draged  item for some seconds then the OVER function block need to b called else not**

```
$('.treeLink').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: '.childLinks',
    over: function() {},
    over: function() {
        getTreeLinks($(this).attr('id').split("treeLink")[1]);
    },
    drop: function() {
        updateGovLinks($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to use some sort of timeout:

```
var timeout;
$('.treeLink').droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: '.childLinks',
    over: function() {
        var self = this;
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
             getTreeLinks($(self).attr('id').split("treeLink")[1])
        }, 4000);
    },
    out: function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    },
    drop: function() {
        updateGovLinks($(this).attr('id'));
    }
});
```